# how to insert a line break in a dialog box angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, formatting

I have angular button `<button body='Do you confirm? \n {{myFunction()}}'></button>` and it is bind to a method in my component.ts file

```
myFunction = (): string => {
     return 'hello \n world';
}.
```

I coudn't get the newline in the output.

Comment: Actually using a function to transform a text is a bad practice, try it by using a pipe.
and the line problem could be fixed just adding a limit width for the button it will wrap the text by it self

Comment: @AbelValdez Can you show me an example?

Comment: <button body='Do you confirm? &nbsp; hello  &nbsp; world'></button>

Comment: @AbelValdez not working for me Can you solve it using a pipe?

Answer (score 0):

It will help you with your main problem that is the new line.

```
<button> Do you confirm? </br> hello </br> world</button>
```

But actually I recommend to you read about creating a custom pipe to transform the data and prevent call a function each time the DOM be update.

Comment: not working for me

Comment: Ready I just update the answer

Comment: ```<button body='Do you confirm? \n {{myFunction()}}'></button>``` This is the button I am using the body is inside the tag

Comment: You dont need it

Comment: I am using the body tag inside the button to display the content of the UI